# Google app Script get range copy data if cell not blank

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, copy, is-empty

I have a script someone else created, I am new to app script and still learning, I am copying a range of data from sheet1 that they fill in daily to sheet2, I would like this to not copy the row if Column F is blank.  Here is what I am using currently.

```
       function CopyData(CopyData) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("2019-02-03");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Archive Data");

  sheet1.getRange("A2:Q16").copyTo(sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,1,1,1), {contentsOnly:true});

}
```

Comment: Read about conditional logic in javascript

Comment: Thank you , I will definitely read up on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function CopyData(CopyData) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName("2019-02-03");
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName("Archive Data");
  var rg1=sh1.getRange("A2:Q16");
  var vA=rg1.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(vA[i][5]){
      sh2.appendRow(vA[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you for quick response.  I learn more everyday.